# Formatting a list of times to a 24 hour format to be used as xtick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib graph, with values on the y, and times on the x. The xtick lables however range from 0 to 23, which while correct I would like them formatted as 0:00, 1:00 etc.

I read the data from a csv file and extract the hour value by doing : `hour_counts = songs['hour'].value_counts().sort_index()` which returns a list like so:

`0      574
1      399
2      225
3      135
23     734`

A graph is then plotted, and the xticks displayed by doing:

`ax = hour_counts.plot()
 ax.set_xticks(hour_counts.index)
 ax.set_xticklabels(hour_counts.index, rotation=45)`

This creats a graph like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wdDK.jpg

I would like to format the xticks so they look like the time, 0:00, 1:00, 2:00 all the way to 23:00.

Thanks

Comment: You can try using `ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))`. For more info, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167835/matplotlib-formatting-of-timestamp-on-x-axis)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work, I think beacuse I am plotting the index of the list, it isnt explictly a datetime datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple and easy hack you can try at least for the plot you posted is the following

```
ticklabels = ['%s:00' %i for i in range(24)]
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels, rotation=45)
```

One can also use `format` to format the ticklabels as per your need.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you